# How to load multiple dividend data from yahoo finance?

Tags: r, stock

I'm trying to load dividend data, but I have no idea how to get multiple stocks data.

When I run

```
library(quantmod)
Data <- getDividends( "EIG", from= "2020-01-01", to="2020-07-18", src="yahoo")
```

I got

```
               EIG.div
2020-03-03      0.25
2020-05-05      0.25
```

The problem is that I need to import more than one stock dividend data. I simply tried by writing:

```
Tick <- c("CC", "EIG")
CCC <- getDividends( Tick, from= "2020-01-01", to="2020-07-18", src="yahoo")
```

and it gives only CC's data. What to change to import both of them in one code?

Comment: I'd probably use `lapply(Tick, function(sym) getDividends(sym, from=..., to=..., src="yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE))` (but I"m not a `quantmod` user, so perhaps there's a more idiomatic way to do it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `getDividends` (and `quantmod` in general) returns an `xts` time series object.  Code could be:

```
library(xts)
library(quantmod)

Tick <- c("CC","EIG")
divs <- xts()
for( sym in Tick) {
  divs <- merge(divs, getDividends( sym, from= "2020-01-01", to="2020-07-18", src="yahoo"))
}
```

Because the class of `divs` is `xts`, R will use `merge.xts` from the `xts` package to do the merge.  The result is:

```
> divs
                     CC.div EIG.div
2020-02-25 18:00:00   0.25      NA
2020-03-02 18:00:00     NA    0.25
2020-05-04 19:00:00     NA    0.25
2020-05-13 19:00:00   0.25      NA
```

Comment: I'm so sorry to say thank you. This is what I'm looking for!